# vim-fireplace cpp don't evaluate every time

Tags: vim, clojure

I'm having trouble with [vim-fireplace](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fireplace) using the cpp command.

[image: Animated GIF]

I'm only using cpp to evaluate the println but at some random point vim enters insert mode and overwrites whatever I type. <kbd>ESC</kbd> don't work, only <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd>.

This problem is only on my Ubuntu machine, on Mac it works fine.

Here is my vimrc.

```
filetyp plugin indent on

"set noswapfile

" set filetype detection
filetype on


" VIM-PLUGGED settings ---------------------- {{{
" Specify a directory for plugins
" - For Neovim: ~/.local/share/nvim/plugged
" - Avoid using standard Vim directory names like 'plugin'
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')

" Make sure you use single quotes

" On-demand loading
Plug 'scrooloose/nerdtree', { 'on':  'NERDTreeToggle' }
Plug 'tpope/vim-fireplace', { 'for': 'clojure' }
Plug 'vim-scripts/paredit.vim', { 'for': 'clojure' }
" Any valid git URL is allowed
" Plug 'https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline.git'

" Initialize plugin system
call plug#end()
" :PlugInstall
" }}}

" GUI set number
set numberwidth=1
set number
" highlight search
set hlsearch incsearch


let mapleader = ","
let maplocalleader = ","
set tabstop=2       " The width of a TAB is set to 4.
set shiftwidth=2
set softtabstop=2
set expandtab

" MAPPINGS
let mapleader = ","
let maplocalleader = ","
inoremap jk <esc>

nnoremap <c-j> 5<c-e>
nnoremap <c-k> 5<c-y>
nnoremap ff :execute "noh"<cr>
" edit vimrc
:nnoremap <leader>ev :vsplit $MYVIMRC<cr>
:nnoremap <leader>sv :source $MYVIMRC<cr>
:nnoremap <leader>ec :split $VIMSETUP/cheetsheet<cr>
:nnoremap <leader>en :split $VIMSETUP/notes<cr>

"  Clojure file settings ---------------------- {{{
augroup filetype_clojure
  autocmd!
  " autocmd FileType clojure nnoremap J gJ
  autocmd FileType clojure nmap <leader>e cpp
  autocmd FileType clojure nnoremap <leader>r :Require<cr>
augroup END
" }}}
" Vimscript file settings ---------------------- {{{
augroup filetype_vim
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType vim setlocal foldmethod=marker
augroup END
" }}}

nnoremap <c-b> :NERDTreeToggle<cr>
```

Comment: Try reproducing with just the Fireplace plugin, and if positive, report this to the plugin's author.